# pdf file couldn't load on deployment but it can work succesfull on local

Tags: java, pdf, jasper-reports

I need your help, I'm in trouble.

I have to do one report on my project. I did it and it works good. I send request from browser and my java code generate report via jasper add response and chrome show it.

Our system engineer deploy project on last day. My report file(.pdf) couldn't load. We don't understand why? Chrome says "Failed load pdf file", Firefox and IE show bytecodes on notepad. We look to log file but no error, no exception.

Here is my java report code:

```
@Path("print")
@GET
@UnitOfWork
@Produces("application/pdf")
public Response print(@Context HttpServletResponse response,
                      @QueryParam("mbsFileOid") String mbsFileOid,
                      @QueryParam("followAfterDate") Date followAfterDate,
                      @QueryParam("fileOid") long fileOid,
                      @Context UriInfo allUri) throws IOException{
    OutputStream stream = response.getOutputStream();

    List<Commitment> commitments = commitmentDao.findAllCommitmensByFileOid(""+fileOid);
    List<CommitmentsReportValue> commitmentsReportValues = new ArrayList<>();
    DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    for (Commitment commitment : commitments) {
        CommitmentsReportValue commitmentsReportValue = new CommitmentsReportValue();
        commitmentsReportValue.setAmount(commitment.getAmount().toString());
        commitmentsReportValue.setSortId(""+commitment.getSortId());
        commitmentsReportValue.setCommitmentDate(sdf.format(commitment.getCommitmentDate()));
        commitmentsReportValues.add(commitmentsReportValue);
        if(commitment.getCommitmentStatus() == Commitment.CommitmentStatus.NotPaid)
            commitmentsReportValue.setStatus("Ödenmedi");
        else
            commitmentsReportValue.setStatus("Ödendi");
    }
    CoverCalculationDTO coverCoverCalculationDTO = mbsFileDao.getCoverCalculation(mbsFileOid,followAfterDate);
    coverCoverCalculationDTO.setFollowTotalInterest(""+coverCoverCalculationDTO.getFollowAfterTotalInterest());
    coverCoverCalculationDTO.setTotalBalance(""+coverCoverCalculationDTO.getLastTotalBalance());

    MbsFile mbsFile = mbsFileDao.findById(mbsFileOid);
    try {
        buildAggregateReport(mbsFile,coverCoverCalculationDTO,commitmentsReportValues).toPdf(stream);
    } catch (DRException e) {

        LOGGER.info(e.getMessage());

    }

    response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"rapor.pdf\"");

    stream.flush();
    stream.close();
    return Response.ok().build();
```

And here is the screen shot from my local server:

[image]

And here is the ss from deployment on chrome:
[image]

And here is ss from deployment on firefox:
[image]

It sounds to me ridiculous. It works perfect on my local computer but didn't work on deployment and no errors no execptions.

Could you help me please?

Comment: No real idea but, maybe you try to add content-length to header..

Comment: I can try but I can't foreseen pdf file length. It's changable.

Comment: You can first load into a ByteArrayOutputStream check lenght, set the content-lenght header and the output it to the response stream. (but hey I don't know if it solves the problem.)

Comment: Ok, I'll try and push it. After the deployment I'll see.Thank you.